# How to print even numbers using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I find this simple "for loop" exercise.

> Using a for loop print all even numbers up to and including n. Don’t include 0.
>
> ```
> let n1 = 22; 
>
> // Example output: 
>
> // 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 OR each item on a new line
> ```

I found a way to solve this but I don't think its elegant at all.

Here is my code:

```js
let n1 = 22;

for (let i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    
   let  b = i * 2;

    if (b <= n1){
        if (b == 0) {} else 
        { console.log('Count',b);}
    };
       
};
```

How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2):

Just count by twos:

```js
for (let i=2; i <= 22; i+=2) {
     console.log('Count', i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i=2; i <= 22; i+=2) {
     console.log(i);
}
```

all the best

Answer (score 0):

Here using [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop:

```js
const count = { index: 0, n1: 22 }

while(count.index < count.n1) {
  console.log('Count', count.index += 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```